# Mysql WHERE field containing JSON variable

Tags: mysql, database, json, codeigniter

I have a database having a filed `myfield` containing json string:`["2","4","1","6"]` OR `["1"]` . I want to make a filter for this filed and was thinking to query it with:

`SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE myfield = '5'` -> this return can not echo **id** because `["2","4","1","6"]` does not have the value 5.

`SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE myfield = '1'` -> return can echo **id**-> because -> in json string on filed `myfield` have the value 1.

how can fix it? what do i do?

I tried as but it don't work for me:

`SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE myfield = '1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for `id=1` for instance you can do

```
SELECT 1 as id
FROM table_name 
WHERE find_in_set('1', replace(myfield, '"', '')) > 0
```

You can use it like this in your code

```
$this->db->query("SELECT 1 as id 
                  FROM table_name 
                  WHERE find_in_set('1', replace(myfield, '\"', '')) > 0");
```

Comment: I use it on codeigniter as: `$row = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE find_in_set(5, replace(myfield, '"', '')) > 0')->row();` and echo result as:
`echo $row->fieldname;` and getting this error:`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER)` what do i do?

Comment: I don't know. I see no `1` in your query. Do you have an `id` column in your table?

Comment: BTW you should delimit your strings with `"` instead of `'`: `$row = $this->db->query("SELECT...`

Comment: Delimit your query with `"` as I said. If you don't then you will end the query with the next `'`

Comment: I use of `"` it interferes with `..., '"', ...` and have error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '', '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)`????

Comment: How is it in the my query?

Comment: I use it as: `$this->db->query(\"SELECT 1 as id FROM table_name WHERE find_in_set('1', replace(myfield, '"', '')) > 0\");` and getting this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"SELECT 1 as id FROM table_nam' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in ...`

Comment: It is the other way around: `$this->db->query("SELECT 1 as id FROM table_name WHERE find_in_set('1', replace(myfield, '\"', '')) > 0");`

Answer (score 0):

The given solution by @juergen will not work if you search first or last item . For this you need to replace square brackets also . This worked for me

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_tasks_weekly` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(`myfield`,']','') ,  '[',''),'\"',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use serialization and deserialization to save or retrieve data from database field.